# Missing Method Exception When Referencing .Net Standard Project From .Net 4.6.1 Unit Test

Tags: c#, mstest, .net-standard, vstest, .net-standard-2.0

I am getting the following exception when running a .Net 4.6.1 unit test that uses `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open`, if the unit test project references a .Net Standard 2.0 assembly:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(System.String, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode)'.
    at UnitTestProject.UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
```

The unit test project was created using the VS 2017 Unit Test project (not the .NET Core one) and references were added to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` and my standard class library:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string zipfilename = "C:\\temp\\out.zip";
            using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipfilename, ZipArchiveMode.Read)) { }
        }
    }
```

The .net standard class library is simply a single class with no methods:

```
namespace StandardClassLib
{
    public static class Zipper
    { // Class is empty.
    }
}
```

I get the same error using the Test Explorer in Visual Studio and from the command line using `vstest.console.exe`.

Note that this behavior only exhibits itself in a unit test project, Console Applications work fine.

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working and a workaround to this issue (if possible)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens because the test project needs some additional binding redirects that need to be generated during the build process. While the project properties dialog has an option to auto-generate binding redirects, this has no effect for libraries (which classic unit test projects are) so you need to edit the .csproj file manually to include:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more details and explanations, see the announcement GitHub issue [Issues with .NET Standard 2.0 with .NET Framework & NuGet](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31) and its linked discussion issue.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for a unit test project, and I also had to use it on a Console app built against .NET Framework 4.7.