# Referencing .NET Standard project breaks async call

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.2 project with all tests passing, but as soon as I add a reference to a .NET Standard project within the same solution, one of tests breaks (no other change is made, just the reference)

The tests fails here:

```
return await _client.GetAsync(url);
```

With exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>
```

What has happened to cause this? Is it a package in .NET Standard which is overwriting dependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Method Exception When Referencing .Net Standard Project From .Net 4.6.1 Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46348070/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Method Exception When Referencing .Net Standard Project From .Net 4.6.1 Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348070/missing-method-exception-when-referencing-net-standard-project-from-net-4-6-1)